# Prevent background items from receiving focus while using MUI backdrop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, focus

We're dimming the screen when a (custom, not MUI) dialog is open using [MUI backdrop](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-backdrop/) but the "grayed-out" items are still active and the user can access them using the keyboard.

In the below picture I'm moving from "show backdrop" to button 2 and then to button 3...

[image]

Is there a simple way to avoid keyboard access to the background?

Code ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-with-backdrop-s2qt4l)):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function SimpleBackdrop() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleToggle}>Show backdrop</Button>
      <Button>Button 2</Button>
      <Button>Button 3</Button>
      <Button>Button 4</Button>
      <Backdrop
        sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
        open={open}
        onClick={handleClose}
      >
        <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
      </Backdrop>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just trap the focus inside the overlay,
https://v5-0-6.mui.com/components/trap-focus/

```
 <Unstable_TrapFocus open>
                  <Backdrop
                    sx={{ zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
                    open={open}
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                  >
                    <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
                  </Backdrop>
</Unstable_TrapFocus>
```